# How can I efficiently translate a large, non-rectangular 2D list to an even larger rectangular 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a 2-D list of shape (300,000, X), where each of the sublists has a different size (X) and contains integers between 0 and 25. In order to convert the data to a `Tensor`, all of the sublists need to have equal length, but I don't want to lose any data from my sublists in the conversion.

At first glance, I wanted to fill all sublists smaller than the longest sublist with filler (-1) in order to create a rectangular array. For my current dataset, the longest sublist is of length 5037.

My conversion code is below:

`for seq in new_format:
        seq.extend([-1] * (length - len(seq)))`

However, when there are 300,000 sequences in `new_format`, and `length-len(seq)` is generally >4000, the process causes a `MemoryError` due to its enormous size. Most of the sublists become much longer when extended to size 5037 in order to equalize the sublists. How can I make this more space-efficient or avoid the problem entirely?

Comment: are all elements numbers? If so what is their range (typical minimum and maximum) and are these floats or integers?

Comment: I've updated the question; all elements are integers between 0 and 25.

Comment: Also what does `(300,000, X)` as shape mean? `300 x 0 x X`? The three zeros don't make sense.

Comment: To store an array you are going to need `1511100000*size_of_dtype` bytes. If `size_of_dtype` is 1: (e.g. uint8, or bool) you'll require 1.5111 gigs. You if you need someting like a 64bit float, it will require 12 gigs. And that is just the array.

Comment: 300,000 x X is the shape of the array. To access the third integer in the first sublist, you'd do new_format[0][2].

Comment: so the first dimension is only of size 300? I'm not sure how 300 x 5000 could be a MemoryError.

Comment: Well, the good news is *you can use np.uint8* so you'll be able to efficiently store this.

Comment: The first dimension is of size 300,000. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga He wants to extend with -1, not sure how that fits into `uint8`. :) Did you mean `int8`?

Comment: @MSeifert a yes, I forgot about the filler being negative, but `int8` will work!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That likely won't solve my problem, since the array is still 300000 x 5000, which even at 4 bytes each adds up to 6 Gigabytes in RAM.

Comment: `int8` is only one byte (8 bits = 1 byte) :)

Comment: After thinking about this: I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need that rectangular array? What's the rationale for that? I believe the problem is the approach itself and patching a wrong approach will lead to more problems down the road. Maybe you could include enough informations so we can assist you in finding the correct approach (if one exists).

Comment: @MSeifert given the tags, likely to pass this data into a tensorflow pipeline, which uses np.arrays

Comment: What kind of operations do you want to do with your big array? If most elements inside are irrelevant (your fillers) it could be a good idea to build a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) to save memory.

Comment: I'd really like to pass this as a non-rectangular 2D array, but TensorFlow seems to expect a train inputs with the same length, where ours are variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But the padding step seems odd. Why pad the array when you want to use them for tensorflow or numpy operations? The padding value will be a problem in/after each operation.

Comment: or is -1 a common "sentinel" for missing values in tensorflow?

Comment: No, its just what we've chosen to pad the array with to make it rectangular (make all inputs the same length).

Comment: @MSeifert yes, it certainly could be problematic, I agree.

Comment: @MSeifert What would you recommend? I'm new to TensorFlow but needed to make all the inputs have the same size. -1 is supposed to represent the absence of information for a given sequence. A -1 in the input is mirrored in the output (input/output array sizes are equal).

Comment: Explain your overall goal. What do you want to do with the rectangular array? Otherwise I can't recommend anything (actually I _could_ recommend a few approaches but if these would work depends on what you want to do with the array).

Comment: @MSiefert Is there a way for me to paste the current TF source code to you? It's essentially just supposed to correlate a given list of amino acids with a list of the structure for each amino acid (there are 7 types of structures, and a "no structure").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice? Don't contruct a Python list to initialize the array. That will be too memory heavy. Since your values fall between 0-25, and you want a filler of -1, you can use `np.int8`:

First, initialize an adequately shaped array with the appropriate filler value:

```
>>> arr = np.full((300000, 5037), -1, dtype=np.int8)
```

Then simply loop over your existing data and set the values as needed.

```
>>> for i, row in enumerate(data):
...     for j, val in enumerate(row):
...         arr[i, j] = val
...
```

This will give you a nice and compact array of about 1.5 gigs:

```
>>> arr.nbytes*1e-9
1.5111
```